# Can I use Terraform to restore my backed up Azure Virtual Machine?

Tags: azure, terraform

I used "azurerm_recovery_services_vault" to create a backup space. OS disks and managed disks are being backed up at 00:00 AM every day.

```
resource "azurerm_recovery_services_vault" "vaultvm" {
  name                = var.backup-vault-name
  location              = var.location
  resource_group_name   = var.system-rg
  sku                 = "Standard"

  soft_delete_enabled = true
}

resource "azurerm_backup_policy_vm" "backup" {
  name                = var.backup_name
  resource_group_name   = var.system-rg
  recovery_vault_name = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.vaultvm.name

  timezone                       = var.timezone
  instant_restore_retention_days = var.days

  backup {
    frequency = "Daily"
    time      = "00:00"
  }

  retention_daily {
    count = 7
  }

}
```

What I want to know is whether we can restore these backed up VMs using terraform.

Answer (score 1):

According with the [azurerm_backup_protected_vm](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/backup_protected_vm) resource, it should be possible.

Previously, it was possible leveraging the [azurerm_recovery_services_protected_vm](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/1.43.0/docs/resources/recovery_services_protected_vm) resource

Comment: Isn't "azurerm_backup_protected_vm" where the information about the virtual machine to be backed up goes?

Comment: What I want to know is whether we can restore these backed up VMs using terraform.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will need to import the vm you are trying to restore and then reference the OS and managed disks to that vm

```py
     data "azurerm_virtual_machine" "example" {
          name                = "somename"
          resource_group_name = "somename"
        }
        
     output "virtual_machine_id" {
          value = data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example.id
        }
        
     resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "example" {
         name = data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example.name
        resource_group_name ="groupname"
        location =""
        
     storage_os_disk {
        name = ""
        create_option = "FromImage"
        image_uri = "/path/.vhd"
        }
        
     storage_data_disk {
        name = ""
        create_option = "FromImage"
        image_uri = "/path/.vhd"
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to know is whether we can restore these backed up VMs using terraform.

The below **Terraform** to define `Azure resources` and a null resource with a local-exec provisioner to run an `az backup restore restore-disks` command using the Azure CLI.

**Terraform**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
data "azurerm_virtual_machine" "azurevm" {
    name    = "vm_name"
    resource_group_name = "<ResourceGroup>"
}

data "azurerm_recovery_services_vault" "azurevm" {
    name    = "rcrvault"
    resource_group_name = "<ResourceGroup>"
}

resource "null_resource" "powershell" {
  triggers = {
    vault_id        = data.azurerm_recovery_services_vault.azurevm.id
    protected_vm_id = data.azurerm_virtual_machine.azurevm.id
  }
  
provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = <<-EOT
        az backup restore restore-disks --container-name "<container-name>" --item-name MyItem --resource-group "<ResourceGroup_Name>" --rp-name <recovery-point_name> --storage-account "<Storage-Account-name>" --vault-name <vaultname>
        EOT
      }
}
```

When you run the code, the `az backup restore restore-disks` command will be executed using the `Azure CLI`. The command is responsible for **restoring disks** from a specified recovery point in **Azure Backup**.

**Terraform apply**

[image]

Reference: [az backup restore restore-disks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/backup/restore?view=azure-cli-latest#az-backup-restore-restore-disks)